# Doctrine query builder ~ datetime

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a simple chatbox in symfony2 / doctrine 2.

For testing I'm checking for new messages every 5 seconds, so in my query I try to get all messages by getting all messages with a datetime greater than the current one minus 5 seconds.

I try to do so the following way, but it returns all messages in the database instead of the ones posted in the last 5 seconds

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m')
                 ->from('ChatboxBundle:ChatMessage', 'm')
                 ->where(':new > :last')
                 ->setParameter('new', 'm.postdate' )
                 ->setParameter('last', new \DateTime('-5 second'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
$updatedata = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`m.postdate` is a field name and therefore shouldn't be passed in as a parameter. Try this

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m')
                 ->from('ChatboxBundle:ChatMessage', 'm')
                 ->where('m.postdate > :last')
                 ->setParameter('last', new \DateTime('-5 second'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
$updatedata = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Yeah it's a long time ago since this answer, in Symfony 4.3 i had to use `Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE` as simply `DATETIME` was already deprecated

Comment: is there a diff between DATETIME_MUTABLE and DATETIME_IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 0):

Note thats You don't need to use   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME

The [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html) say :
Calling setParameter() automatically infers which type you are setting as value. This works for integers, arrays of strings/integers, **DateTime** instances and for managed entities. If you want to set a type explicitly you can call the third argument to setParameter() explicitly. It accepts either a PDO type or a DBAL Type name for conversion.